# Sum the total hours and group by hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to group by all the hours between 0 and 40 into one total sum.
41 - 50 into one total sum and 50+ into another sum.

```
select hours,
       sum(hours)
from   employee
where  hours between 0 and 40
group by hours;
```

The above query groups by the hours, so i have the results split by hours, like if I have 1, 2.3, 0.5, 35.5, 30 etc.

```
1       403
2.3     4.6
0.5     53
35.5    284
30      1230
```

But I want something like
`403+4.6+53+284+1230 = 1974.6` because they all fall under 40 
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregation, grouping by a value that builds intervals of hours.
By your example, you can have not integer values, so you should use explicit relational operators to have, for example, 40.1 in 40-50 group:

```
select sum(hours),
       case
          when hours <= 40 then '0-40'
          when hours > 40 and hours <= 50 then '41-50'
          when hours > 50 then '50-...'
         end
from employee
group by case
          when hours <= 40 then '0-40'
          when hours > 40 and hours <= 50 then '41-50'
          when hours > 50 then '50-...'
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when hours between 0 and 40 then hours else 0 end) hours_1,
       sum(case when hours between 41 and 50 then hours else 0 end) hours_41,
       sum(case when hours > 50 then hours else 0 end) hours_51
from employee
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP`-ing based on `CASE`

```
select (case when hours between 0 and 40
              then '0 - 40'
              when hours between 41 and 50
              then '41 - 50'
              else
                   '50+'
          end) as hours_range,
        sum(hours) 
from employee
group by (case when hours between 0 and 40
              then '0 - 40'
              when hours between 41 and 50
              then '41 - 50'
              else
                   '50+'
          end);
```

Comment: How can get them as rows, instead of columns, do I have to do a union all with another select ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select '1 to 40',sum(hours)

from   employee
where  hours between 0 and 40

union all

  select '41 to 50',sum(hours)

from   employee
where  hours between 41 and 50

union all

  select '50+',sum(hours)

from   employee
where  hours>50
```

Comment: Which version performs better, `union all` or doing a `case` statement like in the other answers